# @Model or @Html.DisplayFor doesnt work in editortemplates in mvc4

Tags: telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc4 and have a telerik control grid with editing mode enabled. The edit mode is "PopUp" , that means that on click of the edit button, an overlay should appear with some of the fields populated in textboxes and some in labels.

The issue is that the field values are not rendered in labels. Field values are rendered in textboxes for editing which is fine.

**View Model**

```
namespace Admin.Models
{
   public class ViewModel
   {
       public int Id{ get; set; }
       [DataType(DataType.Text)]
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**.cshtml file**

```
@model Admin.Models.ViewModel


<div>
   <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
      @Model.Id **Does not work,always return 0, should    return  value 1,2,...**
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)  **Does not work,always return 0, should    return  value 1,2,...**
   </div>
   <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)  
   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller code**

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   IList<ViewModel> viewModels = GetModelItems();
   return View(new GridModel
   {
      Data = viewModels
   });
}
```

Comment: Do you not indent?  Or do you have an editor that murders good formatting?

Comment: I do but was having an error while posting the question. Reindented.

Comment: which one? does it work for standard for standalone editor in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teleric don't seem to support DisplayFor in editing templates.
In this froum thread they confirm it http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/clajax-databinding-client-editing.aspx#1906385